# What are the steps to install pandas on an Amazon EC2 linux server?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, installation, pandas

When I run:

```
python setup.py install
```

On an amazon ec2 linux instance, I get:

```
Could not locate executable gfortran
Could not locate executable f95
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifc
Could not locate executable lf95
Could not locate executable pgfortran
Could not locate executable f90
Could not locate executable f77
Could not locate executable fort
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable g95
Could not locate executable pathf95
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'posix'
```

What is the way around this? Is there an alternative, straightforward wat to install pandas on an EC2 linux server? Is there an image that is better than others for pandas?

Thx!

Comment: I would just install the anaconda distribution of python.

Comment: For those who closed the question, `pandas` is solely for programming and data science. The type of user needing help with this would not likely wade through server fault.

Comment: @KyleKelley My gut feeling is that this is still not on-topic for Stack Overflow, but since it's only a gut feeling I'm refraining from voting one way or the other.

Comment: If there was a data scientist stack exchange, it would go well there. However, the cross-over between data scientist and programmer is pretty big (and wouldn't belong on Cross Validated either).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Need for build tools

Make to sure install system packages for gcc, g++, gfortran, and python-dev. Here's the setup I would use. First update apt-get, then install...

```
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install build-essential gfortran gcc g++ python-dev
```

## Installing via system packages

Depending on the image, pandas may be part of the system packages

```
$ apt-get install python-pandas
```

It is pretty much guaranteed to be several releases behind though.

## Using pip, built from source

However, if you want the latest and greatest, install from source. Here's a little recipe that installs setuptools & pip followed on by numpy and pandas

```
# Update your apt-get:
apt-get update

# Pre-requisities
apt-get install build-essential gfortran gcc g++ curl wget python-dev

# Make sure you have the latest setup tools 
wget https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py -O - | python2.7

# Get pip
curl --show-error --retry 5 https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py | python2.7

pip install numpy pandas
```

Comment: If you're on centos, swap apt-get for yum.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install gfortran first

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran
```